# cleanest way to access value from pointer or get its default value if null

Tags: c++

I have a pointer to a struct and I want to get either a member of that struct or a default constructed member of that struct if the pointer is null. Is there a nice short way to do this? The only way I can think of implementing something like this atm is with macros

eg:

```
#define safe_dereference(X, Y) (X ? X->Y : decltype(X->Y)())
```

*this snippet was written in stack overflow and has not been tested*

but then I have a macro and I really hate using macros in c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a function instead of MACRO, something like:

```
template <typename C, typename M>
M safe_dereference(const C* c, M (C::*member))
{
    return c ? c->*member : M();
}
```

Call is a little different though:

```
safe_dereference(somePointer, &MyClass::MyMember);
```